# UITableView setRowHeight how to commit changes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, setneedsdisplay, row-height

I have a design where `UITableViewCell`s contains an `UIImageView`. This image should have the same proportion in portrait or landscape, this is why I have a method called when interface orientation changes using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification.

```
-(void)updateRowHeightForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    if(!IS_KNOWN_ORIENTATION(orientation))
        return;

    CGFloat rowHeightPortrait = (IPAD ? 320. : 160.);
    CGFloat widthPortrait = (IPAD ? 768. : 320.);
    CGFloat orientationWidth = (IS_PORTRAIT(orientation) ?
                                (IPAD ? 768. : 320.) :
                                (IPAD ? 1024. : 480.));

    CGFloat resultingRowHeight = rowHeightPortrait * orientationWidth / widthPortrait;

    [self.tableView setRowHeight:resultingRowHeight];
//    [self.tableView reloadData]; /* works if uncommented */
}
```

If the line is not commented the view is redrawn and the row height is set properly. If not, even when using `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]` or `[self.tableView setNeedsLayout]` the new value of the property is not used.

How can I force reloading the UI so the new value is applied ?

It worked for some time using `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` because the `rowHeight` property is set before the interface rotates and is redrawn, but for some strange reasons this method is not called anymore...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

causes the table view to re-evaluate all row heights, so you could try this.

Comment: this is just perfect ! unfortunately, I also have a `UILabel` resizing dynamically to use the whole width if the cell, the text being centered. When I rotate the screen it seems the right of the label is moved, then the text is centered which is not really beautiful to see. If their is any way to have a better behavior I would love to know how, if not this is not very important